# Help finding the title of a children's story with travels through mirrors and the chambers of a shell

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Could you help me find the title of a children's fantasy book?

There was a scene where children were climbing through a mirror, but the mirror had many mirror reflections inside of it.  The children were taking different paths through the mirror and were getting lost.

There was also a scene where the chidren were climbing through different chambers of a shell (nautilus?).

Comment: When did you read this?  Was it an illustrated book?  Were the children searching for something/someone, fleeing someone or just exploring?

Comment: Read in the Late 70's.  I can't remember if it had illustrations.  I don't remember those last details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably Jane Langton's "The Diamond in the Window" (1962). Two children living in an old house in Concord MA retrace in their dreams the similar dream adventures of previous occupants of the house. Summary from Kirkus Reviews:

> Eddy and Eleanor begin rummaging through the attic and discover a
> hidden room where two children lived years ago. According to Aunt
> Lily, Ned and Nora disappeared from their beds along with her fiance,
> Prince Krishna. As Eddy and Eleanor settle down in the mysterious
> beds, they are thrown headlong into a series of dual dreams —exciting
> and colorful — each inspired by Uncle Freddy's quotations from Thorean
> and Emerson or by a possible clue to the hidden treasure.

One of these dreams was inspired by a poem "The Chambered Nautilus". Another was full of mirrors showing images of who you might be or might become, depending on what choices you made in life.

> They walked forward. It was like walking into a maze of mirrors. If
> you walked fearlessly straight ahead, you found yourself within the
> next mirror and approaching two others. You could choose either one,
> then go through that one to two more; choose one of those, and find
> two more. It was as though they stood at this moment at the apex of
> an infinite choice. But once they chose, they would have to stick to
> that part of the maze, and the further they went in, the harder it
> would be to go back.